# Sending emails to many recipients but changing name

Tags: python, email

I've found this code that works to send email to multiple recipients:

```
import smtplib
from email.mime.text import MIMEText

s = smtplib.SMTP('smtp.uk.xensource.com')
s.set_debuglevel(1)
msg = MIMEText("""body""")
sender = 'me@example.com'
recipients = ['john.doe@example.com', 'john.smith@example.co.uk']
msg['Subject'] = "subject line"
msg['From'] = sender
msg['To'] = ", ".join(recipients)
s.sendmail(sender, recipients, msg.as_string())
```

But I want to change the name of the person who receives each email, using a text file that I've got.

Comment: What exactly are you having problems with? How to send more than one mail? How to read a text file?

Answer (score 0):

You have multiple options:

1. JSON files are easy to load (and are string based)
2. Other common data structures for strings (BSON, etc)
3. Simple list in text file

In the third option, your code will look like:

```
file = open("receipients.txt", "r") 
receipients =  file.readlines(): 

...
```